# What are 'Air Support Units', and what do they do?

Tags: atwar

I won my last game in atWar (for the first time!), and now I have a bunch of shiny SP to spend on some upgrades.  Most of them have pretty straightforward descriptions (stealth units can't be seen on the map, for example), but there's one that doesn't really tell you what it does.

[image: Air Support]

> Unlocks Air Support units (f.e. Sentry plane)

Now I've tried Googling it, but all that turns up are hits to strangely empty pages on the game's official forums that don't appear to have any threads at all in them.

Anybody know what air support does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air Support units provide support capabilities such as increased view range and stealth detection, depending on the level of customization in your particular game.

[image]

As you can see, most support units tend to have low damage, but they have a much higher view range than other units.